# How to print list items with their type previous text?

Tags: python, list, printing, items

I have a list with different types of items, for example:
`list = [2137, 11.22, 3+4j, True, 'nationality', (0, -99), [4, 18], {"class":'A', "section":'3'}]` 
and I want to print list items line by line adding information about the type of the letter item
something like that:

> 2137  is type:     int

Comment: have you tried to use `type()` when printing those items yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try this using a loop:

```
for i in list: 
    print(i, type(i))
```

the out put will be:

```
2137 <class 'int'>
11.22 <class 'float'>
(3+4j) <class 'complex'>
True <class 'bool'>
nationality <class 'str'>
(0, -99) <class 'tuple'>
[4, 18] <class 'list'>
{'class': 'A', 'section': '3'} <class 'dict'>
```

Also you can do this in one line:

```
print(*zip(list,map(type,list)),sep='\n')
```

Note that:

> Do not use `list` as a variable name. list is predefined in python.